# Favoured reaction product in acid catalysed addition of methanol to alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, ethers

I would like to add methanol to an alkene RCH=CH2, catalysed by conc. sulphuric acid. I would like to know which of these endproducts will be preferentially produced:

1. RCH(OMe)-CH3
2. RCH2-CH2OMe

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ethers are hardly made like that.

Comment: Then kindly suggest an alternative method to produce the endproducts from the starting materials.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP asks in the comments, I shall provide a pathway for producing the end products.

#### For $\ce{RCH(OMe)CH_3}$ from $\ce{RCH=CH_2}$:

1. **Electrophilic addition of water across double bond following [Markovnikov’s Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markovnikov%27s_rule)**: 
   Use either [Acid Catalysed Hydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_reaction#Alkenes) or [Oxymercuration-Demercuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymercuration_reaction). $\ce{RCH=CH_2\longrightarrow RCH(OH)CH_3}$
2. **Add a small amount of sodium or sodium hydride**: There is formation of hydrogen gas as the alcohol acts like an acid in presence of $\ce{Na}$ or $\ce{NaH}$: $\ce{RCH(OH)CH_3\longrightarrow RCH(O^-Na^+)CH_3}$
3. **Add iodomethane:** The nucleophilic oxide ion attacks the iodomethane  to form $\ce{RCH(OCH_3)CH_3}$ via [SN2 reaction mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN2_reaction). (Williamson’s Ether Synthesis)

#### For $\ce{RCH_2CH_2OMe}$ from $\ce{RCH=CH_2}$:

1. **Anti-Markovnikov Water Addition**: Use [Hydroboration-Oxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroboration#Reactions_involving_substituted_alkenes).
2. **Add a small amount of sodium or sodium hydride**
3. **Add iodomethane** ([Williamson’s Ether Synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williamson_ether_synthesis))

#### Alternative Idea:

You may want to explore adding aq. acidified methanol solution into $\ce{RCH(OH)CH_3}$ and $\ce{RCH_2CH_2OH}$. This will give you $\ce{RCH(OMe)CH_3}$ as the major product.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ether#Synthesis) for more details.

Comment: Thank you insipidintegrator! My original idea is explained here: https://www.chadsprep.com/chads-organic-chemistry-videos/addition-of-alcohol-to-alkene/  How can I modify this to maximise RCH2CH2OMe ?

Comment: Unfortunately, $\ce{RCH_2CH_2OMe}$ always remains the minor product as the mechanism is an Electrophilic addition involving formation of a carbocation intermediate which is much more stable on a secondary carbon than a primary one. Also, you can get a bit of $\ce{RCH(OH)CH_3}$ because of water addition as a side reaction. (*Note that you cannot operate in* $100$% pure alcohol(as a way of side-stepping the reaction with water) as organic acids do not ionise in non-polar solvents) A pathway to produce the ether you want involves use of diazomethane and $\ce{BF_3}$ with $\ce{RCH_2CH_2OH}$.

Comment: Thanks again, Insipidintegrator. What would adding H2O2 do to the reaction mechanism? Would we get a Kharasch type anti-Markovnikov addition to favour RCH2CH2OMe?

Comment: If you have studied the mechanism of the Kharasch effect, you’ll notice that the first step involves the homolytic cleavage of the radical initiator and subsequently the reagent, i.e. $\ce{HBr}$ (not $\ce{HCl}$ or $\ce{HI}$). I’m not very sure about the viability of the formation of $\ce{CH_3O•}$ radical from methanol. However, I found this: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00328a011 It involves photolysis of methanol.

Comment: Pure alcohols will be protonated by organic acids altho the reaction is promoted by traces of water or by bases such as pyridine.